# Variable substitution in Shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I have declared one variable `IS_abc=false`, on basis of certain condition I am changing value to `IS_abc=true`

```
IS_abc=false
declare -a my_arr
my_arr = ('abc' 'pqr' 'xyz')
....
.... // some operation
IS_abc=true
for i in "${my_arr[@]}"
do
    //here i want to access value of $IS_abc  as true
    //how to do this
done
```

I have tried accessing using `$IS_'$i'` , but it raising error as **invalid substitution**

Tell me if I am doing anything wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use indirect var reference:

```
my_arr=('abc' 'pqr' 'xyz')
IS_abc=true

var="IS_${my_arr[0]}"
echo "${!var}"
```

**Output:**

```
true
```

Comment: What does the `!` do in `"${!var}"`?

Comment: That is called *indirect expansion*. This expands to the name of the variable referenced by parameter. So it prints value of `IS_abc` variable.

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing it like this:

```
value=`eval echo \\${IS_${i}}`
```

There's probably a better way but this should work.